# Probability distribution of $e^X$, when $X ~$ uniform$(0,1)$

Tags: probability-distributions

What is the probability distribution of $e^X$, when $X$ is a random variable and follows the uniform distribution $U(0,1)$?

I noticed that the probability of $e^X$ decays exponentially from $1$ to $e$, even though probability distribution of $U(0,1)$ is constant. Is there an explanation why this is so? Clearly, each number is as likely to be picked, and thus shouldn't each result be equally likely?

Comment: Given a strictly increasing continuous function $g $ and a random variable $X $ with CDF $F $, the CDF of $g (X) $ is $F (g^{-1}(x)) $ where this is defined (elsewhere it is either 0 or 1). This can be generalized to decreasing cases, non-strictly monotone functions, and discontinuous functions, but the monotone city is crucial.

Comment: @Ian Thanks, then the distribution is 1/x, 1<x<2.71. Is there any more information regarding the derivation of the result and such?

Comment: The derivation is pretty simple: if $x$ is in the range of $g$ then $P(g(X) \leq x)=P(X \leq g^{-1}(x))$, because these two events are equivalent as a result of the monotonicity of $g$. If $x$ is not in the range of $g$ then it is either below the range of $g$ or above the range of $g$ (because the image of $g$ is an interval due to the continuity), so the probability is either $0$ or $1$. (Unrelated: I had an autocorrect typo before: "monotone city" should be "monotonicity".)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call $f(x)$ the probability distribution function of the random variable $X$. For a transformation of the form $y = y(x)$ the number of events in a given interval has to be the same regardless of the name you give to the variable

$$
f(x)dx = f(y)dy
$$

or in other words

$$
f(y) = f(x)\left|\frac{dx}{dy} \right|
$$

where the absolute value is there to ensure that the pdf is positive. For $y=e^x$, we have $x = \ln y$ and then $dx/dy = 1/y$. Moreover $f(x) = 1$ because $X\sim u(0,1)$, the result is then

$$
f(y) = 1/y
$$

Here's a small simulation after sampling $x$ and generating $y=e^x$. The dashed line is just $f(y)=1/y$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

$$\because f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & 0\leqslant x \leqslant 1 \\[2ex]
0, & others
\end{cases}
$$

And $Y = e^{X}$

$F_{Y}(x)=P(Y\leqslant x) = P(e^{X}\leqslant x) =P(X\leqslant ln(x))$;

When $ x \leqslant1, F_{Y}(x) = 0$ , $\therefore f_{Y}(x) = 0$.

When $  1\lt x \lt e, F_{Y}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{lnx} 1* dt = \int_0^{lnx} 1* dt = lnx ,  \therefore f_{Y}(x) = 1/x $

When $x > e, F_{Y}(x) = 1,  \therefore f_{Y}(x) = 0$

$$\therefore f_{Y}(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x},  & 0\lt x \lt e \\[2ex]
0, & others
\end{cases}
$$