# Transformation of PDF

Tags: probability

The random variable X has probability density function

\begin{cases} 
      \frac{x}{8} & 0<x<4 \\
      0 & otherwise 
\end{cases}

Find the probability density function of $Z = \log_e (X/4)$

I tried and got this:

\begin{cases} 
      \frac{4e^z}{8} & 0<Z<e^z \\
      0 & otherwise 
\end{cases}
but the limits don't seem right to me, is this correct?

Comment: Hint: what values can $Z$ get for $0<x<1$?

Comment: would it be $0<Z<\infty$?

Comment: @charliejs ?? How do you realize $Z=42$ from some $X$ in $(0,4)$ through the transform $Z=\ln(X/4)$?

Comment: @Did I haven't got $Z=42$??

Comment: You suggested that the range of $Z$ is $(0,\infty)$, right? And $42$ is in $(0,\infty)$, yes? So...

Comment: Please explain the point you're trying to make

Comment: "Please explain the point you're trying to make" Huh??

Comment: @karakfa, did you mean $0 < x < 4$?

Answer (score 4):

if $f(x)$ is the profability density function for $x$ and $z = z(x)$, then the pdf for $z$ can be [calculated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016856/probability-distribution-of-ex-when-x-uniform0-1/2016990#2016990) as

$$
f(z) = f(x)\left|\frac{dx}{dz}\right| \tag{1}
$$

In this case you already know the expression $z=z(x)$:

$$
z = \ln x/4 \quad\Rightarrow\quad x = 4e^{z}
$$

so that

$$
\frac{dx}{dz} = 4e^z
$$

Before replacing in (1) note that when $z(x\to 0^+) = -\infty$, and $z(x=1) = 0$, so the $z$ will range in $(\infty, 0)$. So in the this range

$$
f(z) = f(x)|4e^z| = 2e^{2z} \quad\mbox{for}\quad z<0
$$

or in other words

$$
f(z) = \left\{\begin{array}{lcl} 2e^{2z} &,& z < 0 \\
0 &,& {\rm otherwise}\end{array}\right.
$$

Here's a simulation, the dashed line is the function $2e^{2z}$

[image]