# Pdf of $\sin X$ when $X$ has the pdf $f(x)=\frac{2x}{\pi^2}1_{0<x<\pi}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, transformation

I would like to find the PDF of the random variable $Y=\sin(X)$ given the PDF of $X$:

$$f(x) = \frac{2x}{\pi^2} \text{ for } 0<x<\pi \text{ and } 0 \text{ otherwise}$$

Following the tips in the question here:
[Transformation of PDF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2017371/transformation-of-pdf)

I found $$f(y)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\frac{2\sin^{-1}(y)}{\pi^2}$$

However, I am not sure about the range of $Y$. Is it correct to say that $Y$ is between $1$ and $-1$ for the above $f(y)$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sin\, x$ takes values between $0$ and $1$ when $x$ is between $0$ adn $\pi$, the range for $y$ is $(0,1)$, not $(-1,1)$.  For a proper application of the transformation formula you have to split the range $(0, \pi)$ of $x$ into $(0, \pi /2)$ and $(\pi /2, \pi)$.

Comment: Ops sorry yes I meant between 0 and 1. Is the solution overall correct? I am not sure if the solution itself is correct as the function Y=sin(x) is a many to one function.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, however, according to my understanding and as explained in the link in my question, it seems the function itself doesn't depend on the range. f(y)=f(x) dx/dy