# Given the probability density of random variable $X$, find the probability density of $Y = \sin X$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Given the probability density of random variable $X$:
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{2x}{\pi^2},  & {0 \lt x\lt \pi,} \\[2ex]
0, & {others.}
\end{cases}$$

Find the probability density of $Y = \sin X$.

Here is my work:
$$
h(y): X=\arcsin Y
$$
$$f_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
f_X[h(y)]|h^\acute ' (y)|,  & {0 \lt y \lt 1,} \\[2ex]
0, & {others.}
\end{cases}$$

I got:
$$f(y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{2\arcsin y}{\pi^2 \sqrt {1-y^2}},  & {0 \lt y\lt 1,} \\[2ex]
0, & {others.}
\end{cases}$$

But the answer is:
$$f(y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{\pi \sqrt {1-y^2}},  & {0 \lt y\lt 1,} \\[2ex]
0, & {others.}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3123046/321264

Comment: Thank you!@StubbornAtom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frist of of all calculate

$$F_X(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{2}{\pi^2}t dt=\frac{x^2}{\pi^2}$$

then look at the following drawing

[image]

By definition you have

$$\mathbb{P}[Y>y]=F_X(\pi-\alpha)-F_X(\alpha)=\frac{(\pi-\alpha)^2}{\pi^2}-\frac{\alpha^2}{\pi^2}=1-\frac{2\alpha}{\pi}$$

Thus

$$F_Y(Y)=1-\mathbb{P}[Y>y]=\frac{2\alpha}{\pi}$$

derivating you have your correct solution, having set $\alpha=\arcsin(y)$